# Is there a python equivalent to the Unix `which` command?

Tags: python

I'd like to know where the module I'm about to import is coming from.  Is there a `which` command in python?

Example:

```
>>> which module_name
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/module_name.py
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import imp
imp.find_module(module_name)
```

> Help on built-in function find_module
>   in module imp:
>
> find_module(...)
>       find_module(name, [path]) -> (file, filename, (suffix, mode, type))
>       Search for a module.  If path is omitted or None, search for a
>       built-in, frozen or special module and continue search in sys.path.
>       The module name cannot contain '.'; to search for a submodule of a
>       package, pass the submodule name and the package's `__path__`.

Comment: I've occasionally needed something like this.  I'm glad someone else asked this.  Now I dont feel stupid for not magically knowing where I'm importing all of my libraries from ;)